# Advice for making a new Pandas dataframe with means

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a very basic problem, but I would appreciate some advice. I currently have a way to format the data as needed, but there must be a smarter way to do it. Basically, my data has three columns, "sample", "compound", and "ppb" (concentration). For each sample and compound there are five replicated measurements. For now, I just want to reformat the means for each sample and compound into a new dataframe, where each row is the compound and each column is the sample. Currently, I use:

```
sampleIDList = df['sample'].unique()
compoundIDList = df['compound'].unique()

df0 = df.loc[df['sample'] == sampleIDList[0]]
concMeans0 = []
for compound in compoundIDList:
    dataSubset = df0.loc[df0['compound'] == compound]
    concMeans0.append(dataSubset['ppb'].mean())

df1 = df.loc[df['sample'] == sampleIDList[1]]
concMeans1 = []
for compound in compoundIDList:
    dataSubset = df1.loc[df1['compound'] == compound]
    concMeans1.append(dataSubset['ppb'].mean())

newdf = pd.DataFrame({
    sampleIDList[0]: concMeans0,
    sampleIDList[1]: concMeans1
})

newdf = newdf.set_index(compoundIDList)
```

In this example, there are only two samples. In reality I have many samples, so it's not practical to continue manually building a dataframe column by column, and there must be a better way of doing this. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: a mock data set looks something like this (sorry for the formatting):

```
    sample      compound    ppb
0   sample1     water       103
1   sample1     sugar       15
2   sample1     acid        4
3   sample1     water       107
4   sample1     sugar       19
5   sample1     acid        8
6   sample1     water       104
7   sample1     sugar       18
8   sample1     acid        5
9   sample2     water       115
10  sample2     sugar       54
11  sample2     acid        11
12  sample2     water       126
13  sample2     sugar       65
14  sample2     acid        9
15  sample2     water       124
16  sample2     sugar       44
17  sample2     acid        13
18  sample3     water       112
19  sample3     sugar       34
20  sample3     acid        23
21  sample3     water       114
22  sample3     sugar       35
23  sample3     acid        25
24  sample3     water       110
25  sample3     sugar       33
26  sample3     acid        22
```

and the output I want is something like:

```
        sample1     sample2     sample3
water   104.666667  121.666667  112.000000
sugar   17.333333   54.333333   34.000000
acid    5.666667    11.000000   23.333333
```

Comment: can you share some data?  this looks like a simple use of `pivot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replicates the data you describe.  Calculate the `mean()` then use `unstack()` to make sample a column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"compound":c, "sample":s, "ppd":random.uniform(1,4)} for ppd in range(5) for s in list("12345") 
 for c in list("ABCDEF")])

print(df.shape)
df.groupby(["compound","sample"]).mean().unstack()
```

**output**

```
(150, 3)
               ppd                                        
sample           1         2         3         4         5
compound                                                  
A         2.288282  2.742844  2.552831  2.824470  3.070498
B         2.988021  1.923380  1.827858  2.729828  2.632676
C         2.108418  2.307806  2.585408  2.550337  2.410051
D         2.582997  2.300148  2.304127  2.748143  2.887644
E         2.293815  3.166805  2.523686  2.567653  3.576171
F         2.849908  2.707548  2.928473  2.625358  2.691861
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this works. I knew I was making it much harder than it needed to be!